Why is my correct answer count not incrementing in my C# quiz application?
I'm working on a C# quiz application where I need to track the number of correct answers for each question set. However, the numberOfCorrectAnswers is not incrementing as expected across multiple questions in the same question set.
Here's the code I'm using to save the results to the database:
private void SaveResultsToDatabase(string studentAnswer, string currentQuestion)
{
    string previousQSet = null;
    int correctAnswerCount = 0;

    if (currentQSet != previousQSet)
    {
        correctAnswerCount = GetCorrectAnswerCount(studentId, currentQSet);
        previousQSet = currentQSet;
    }

    string result = studentAnswer == correctAnswer ? "Correct" : "Incorrect";

    if (result == "Correct")
    {
        correctAnswerCount++;
    }

    string query = "INSERT INTO studentAnswers (studentId, qSet, teacherId, question, studentAnswer, correctAnswer, result, numberOfCorrectAnswers) " +
                   "VALUES (@studentId, @qSet, @teacherId, @question, @studentAnswer, @correctAnswer, @result, @numberOfCorrectAnswers);";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-SLFC1BQ5\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=quizDB;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentId", studentId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qSet", currentQSet);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherId", teacherId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", currentQuestion);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentAnswer", studentAnswer);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correctAnswer", correctAnswer);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@result", result);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numberOfCorrectAnswers", correctAnswerCount);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

I’ve tried retrieving the correct answer count from the database and incrementing it, but the count doesn’t update as expected. What might be going wrong, and how can I correctly implement the increment logic for numberOfCorrectAnswers?

Do you mean that GetCorrectAnswerCount(studentId, currentQSet) isn't returning the value you expect?  Have you looked at that method?  What debugging have you done?

Some recommended reading: AddWithValue is evil

Have you tried stepping through with a debugger to see where the values might be different? This could be any number of things, such as case sensitivity issues in string result = studentAnswer == correctAnswer or GetCorrectAnswerCount returning a different value than expected.

OT Great that you are using parameters!

You don't need to store numberOfCorrectAnswers: you can SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [studentAnswers] WHERE [studentAnswer] = [correctAnswer] AND [studentId] = @studentId AND [qSet] = @qSet.

My guess is that you're inserting a new record into the database when a correct answer is given, but when you call GetCorrectAnswerCount you always get the first record for that student and question set, which has an answer count of 1.
If that is the problem, one solution could be to check for an existing record and UPDATE is instead of inserting a new one.  But that's just an immediate fix - there could be other ways to solve the problem in more sophisticated ways.
The point is that you learn to debug the program to see what's actually happening, and then coming up with ways to change the behavior to what you actually want.
The setting of result and the increment of the answer count could be combined better but I don't think that's the source of your problem.

More fundamentally, there's a problem with the database not being correctly normalized.  OP failed to model the many-to-one relationship between quiz questions and question sets

I think you might be facing the issue every time you are calling your method SaveResultsToDatabase you are resetting your correctAnswerCount to 0.
You should store the correctAnswerCount outside the SaveResultsToDatabase method.
So you code should be like this:
public class QuizHandler
{
private string previousQSet = null;
private int correctAnswerCount = 0;

private void SaveResultsToDatabase(string studentAnswer, string currentQuestion, string currentQSet, int studentId, int teacherId, string correctAnswer)
{
    // Check if we are working with a new question set
    if (currentQSet != previousQSet)
    {
        correctAnswerCount = GetCorrectAnswerCount(studentId, currentQSet);
        previousQSet = currentQSet;
    }

    string result = studentAnswer == correctAnswer ? "Correct" : "Incorrect";

    // Increment correctAnswerCount if the answer is correct
    if (result == "Correct")
    {
        correctAnswerCount++;
    }

    string query = "INSERT INTO studentAnswers (studentId, qSet, teacherId, question, studentAnswer, correctAnswer, result, numberOfCorrectAnswers) " +
                   "VALUES (@studentId, @qSet, @teacherId, @question, @studentAnswer, @correctAnswer, @result, @numberOfCorrectAnswers);";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-SLFC1BQ5\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=quizDB;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentId", studentId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qSet", currentQSet);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teacherId", teacherId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", currentQuestion);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentAnswer", studentAnswer);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correctAnswer", correctAnswer);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@result", result);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numberOfCorrectAnswers", correctAnswerCount);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

}
